# Why does clflush needs +m constant

Tags: linux, x86, kernel, cpu-cache

I found that [in Linux kernel, the `clflush` function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/special_insns.h?v=4.3#L193) is implemented as

```
asm volatile("clflush %0" : "+m" (*(volatile char __force *)__p));
```

I don't quite understand why +m is used here?

In my understanding, shouldn't it be implemented as

```
asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
```

Comment: If anything, the obvious way to write it would be `asm volatile ("clflush %0" :: "m"(*(char*)p))`.  There's no need to force the compiler to use a simple `(%reg)` addressing mode with no displacement or index.  **The part that's surprising and interesting is the `+`, not the `m`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either form of the instruction works since they both refer to the same address. However, by using `+m` as the constraint, it ensures that any optimization done with the code (since the function is inline) doesn't assume the data stored in the pointer `__p` is preserved. In other words, it prevents invalid optimization.

Comment: Or to put it another way: It (tries to) make sure the compiler doesn't have part of the cache line still stored in registers.  It would sort of defeat the purpose of the flush if the very next instruction wrote a register to the cache line.

Comment: I see. It forces the compiler to reload the content instead of reusing the content stroed in the cache

Comment: Without the `+`, I think you'd need a `"memory"` clobber, which would be worse for the optimizer.  Possibly declaring it as an input-only memory operand would work, but using an input/output operand is safer because it forces the compiler to treat it as part of the dependency chain involving that memory.  `asm volatile` may not always be sufficient to avoid reordering.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what bad effect may happen if the compiler reorder the instructions. It seems to me that it just flush the content to cache and if the address is used later, it will reload it. Even though compiler reorder the instruction, shouldn't the processor still see the same value since clflush does not modify anything?